# How to deploy a web application

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, tomcat, servlets

I have created a dynamic web projects in eclipse which includes jsp pages and servlet.The back end of this application is Mysql and i include mysql-connector-java-5.1.15-bin.jar in the lib folder. I want to deploy this web application using Tomcat server instead of running this application in eclipse using tomcat.  How is it possible?. Can any one suggest any sample codes or methods to solve this problem.

Comment: Usually you'd build a war file and throw that at Tomcat.

Comment: Ok. I am building a war file .In tomcat folder their are so many subfolders.in which folder i place this war file.How can i acess the index.jsp page of the application using a browser

Comment: copy the WAR file to Tomcats webapps folder and it should auto deploy.

Comment: Thanks will-hartung your answer is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

copy the WAR file to Tomcats webapps folder and it should auto deploy. answer by Will Hartung is correct

Answer (score 0):

you need to build a war file (or ear depending on which technologies you use), and then deploy that to your container.  (in the `tomcat/webapps` folder i believe).  Ant and Maven, two popular technologies for managing a project, both support doing this.  There is plenty of documentation on the web as well

http://www.vaannila.com/ant/ant-sample-build-file-war-1.html

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Go to Windows > SHow View  > Other > Select Servers
Step 2: In Server Tab . Right Click > Add New Server > Add Run time if not available and add tomcat server.

Step 3:  Add your project to it and finish. If you will see in Server tab, you will see your project.

Step 4:  Right click on server and choose either debug or run.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ant build script by running that script from your eclipse your web application will automatically deploy into your tomcat. Another one option is to copy the war file into the tomcat's webapps folder

Answer (score 0):

After export your application from Eclipse to .WAR file you can deploy, undeploy and reload it at Tomcat Web Application Manager Panel: http://localhost:8080/manager/html.